# Installing CM and Broker databases on separate servers

Tags: configuration, 2009, broker

Currently, we have CM and Broker database on the same database server. Now, we want to separate these two to balance the load on the database server itself.

I found we need to change the broker.conf file (if we place the broker config in separate server). Any other change is required?

Is there any other config changes required if we change the broker database to a new server, as per general scenarios (for outbound/search/Tridion MMC (though it points to CM database)?

Is there any issues if we separate these two schemas in different servers?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not run into any issues. SDL will always recommend installing these two databases on different machines. It is a fully supported scenario.

If you are moving your Broker DB to the new machine, all  you should need to do is edit your `cd_broker_conf.xml` (for 2009) or `cd_storage_conf.xml` (for 2011 or 2013).

**NOTE: Most implementations have more than one Broker/Storage config file, so make sure you update them all.**

If you have any custom Content Delivery code that queries the Broker DB directly, that will need to be updated.

Best of luck with your changes.

Comment: Just on the point "Most implementations have more than one Broker/Storage config file, so make sure you update them all". We are using 2009 and the broker.conf file is resides in the deployer srever i.e. in one place only (we hve single deployer in place). Please suggest.

Comment: Depending on your setup, you could have a `cd_broker_conf.xml` with your Deployer and one with your website. Just make sure that all `cd_broker_conf.xml` files are pointing to the right database, if you have only one, then that job is easy.